# Setting dijit.editor content

Tags: dojo

How can I set the content of a `dijit.editor` after it has loaded?

The [following](http://dojotoolkit.org/community/#nabble-td889230) is a solution but I am using `<script type='dojo/method'>` a lot because crome and opera don't like `dojo.connect(nodeId, 'onclick', function(){ ... });` (though firefox seems happy). I tried `<script type="dojo/method" event="onLoadDeferred">` but it just threw up an error.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

If you can't load content into an editor how are you surposed to used it to update content?

Comment: I tried using `this.replaceEditorContent(...)` from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org$maven2@org.apache.cocoon$cocoon-ajax-impl@1.0.0-RC1@org$apache$cocoon$dojo$resources$tests$widget$Editor$test_Editor2_replace.html) without much sucess

Comment: Can you post what your html markup looks like?

Comment: It's nothing special just simple `<div rows="10" dojoType="dijit.Editor" name="letter_header" id="editor_letter_header">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a stupid answer, but have you simply tried putting the value inside the declaration of the dijit.Editor?

For example:

```
<body class="claro">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.Editor" id="myEditor">
        This is the initial value of the editor
    </div>
</body>
```

This will create the editor and set the value of the editor to be whatever text is inside the dijit.Editor markup ("This is the initial value of the editor").

If you need to programmatically change the value of the editor AFTER it has loaded, it seems like you can just use editor.set('value', 'some new text');

For example:

```
<body class="claro">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.Editor" id="myEditor">
        This is the initial value of the editor
    </div>

    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button">
      Click to change editor value
       <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick">
           var editor = dijit.byId('myEditor');
           editor.set('value','this is the new value');
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

I put together the working sample above in a jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Vu4NF/1/

Comment: That does work but I have a problem with submitting the content (I think its something to do with an iFrame). My post data does not show the content of the editor, so I am loading it into a hidden field and then putting that data in the editor for loading and then copying the contents of the editor into a hidden field when it is submitted

Comment: The editor does use an iframe which would prevent it from being submitted with the rest of the form. One way of solving this (as described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073811/submitting-a-form-with-a-dojo-rich-text-editor) is to use dojo/method event="onChange" to populate the hidden field as you type in the dijit.Editor.  Another useful question for submitting the dijit.Editor values: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695581/submit-the-dijit-editor-contents

Comment: I have marked this as the right answer because I'm using dojo/dojango/django the answer is a mixture of the above using hidden fields, a onChange function and a customSave in forms.py.